# SSRS Report Page Break Logic for Groups in a single report

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have created an SSRS table element where we have multiple grouped items like below generated in a Portrait mode.

Problem:
  Whenever there are many items in a single group, some items in the group get spilled over to the next page. That is, a page break is applied.

Example,

If there are 3 groups in a table, and 2nd group contains 50 items, 30 are displayed on the first page, page breaks and then the remaining 20 are displayed on the second page and so on until all the remaining groups are displayed. This is a normal scenario which happens by default.

Expected Solution:
What is expected is, if the data region of any of the group spills over to the next page, then the whole group along with the group header needs to be shifted to the next page. The idea is to have the whole data region of the group stay together.
This is like a smart table (group split).
This is dynamic in nature in the sense, where if for a group with less rows, it fits and stays together on a single page, then page break doesn't happen.

I tried multiple options like below but none of them worked.
 - Change the Keep Together flag of the Grouped rows and the Data Region to True.
 - Add a page break after each row group using the Group properties.

Can someone please let me know if there is at all a way to achieve the smart page break like the one expected above?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but there are two ways that you can do.

1. You can remove paging of SSRS report. to remove Paging by opening property window of report and set InteractiveSize's Height value to 0. it will remove paging of the report

[image: Please see attached image for reference.]

2. You can repeat your Group header if there to another page as well so that user have idea about this data belongs to which group.